# How to spend an imported rawtr() descriptor with bitcoin-cli?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-cli, output-script-descriptors, p2tr

I created a [transaction](https://mempool.space/signet/tx/26651571eb31f9ea4f400615bd5fb834a2b0aa120a03074eac889651ffefbd0d) that creates a taproot output that can be spent using the private key (`KEY`) corresponding to the taproot output key. Then I imported the WIF formatted private key into Bitcoin Core with `importdescriptors '[{"desc: rawtr(KEY), "timestamp":"now" ..."}]'`, which was successful. With `listdescriptors` I can see that it is in the wallet but with `listunspent` the taproot output does not show up.

How can I tell the wallet to recognize the taproot output as spendable?

I've also tried setting the descriptor to active but then it tells me only ranged descriptors can be active and I'm unsure how to add a range to a `rawtr(KEY)` descriptor.

Comment: Can you retrieve the transaction using `gettransaction`? If not, try rescanning the blockchain first.

Comment: Yes, I can retrieve it with `bitcoin-cli -chain=signet gettransaction 26651571eb31f9ea4f400615bd5fb834a2b0aa120a03074eac889651ffefbd0d
`. The wallet I'm doing this with contains multiple descriptors and the rawtr descriptor looks like this: `{
      "desc": "rawtr(83462993476e9310eda5cd58c3597f64aa25c68c03ef37dfd69cf46a7bfb26b8)#m8wpngyu",
      "timestamp": 1670360788,
      "active": false
    }`

Comment: Is that what you used to import or what `listdescriptors` returns?

Comment: This is what `listdescriptors` returns

Comment: I think it always returns the public key in canonical form (hex) instead of the private key which is bas58 (WIF).

Comment: Everything works now. I added an EDIT to the question but am unsure if this is the proper etiquette. Should I delete the question instead?

Comment: If you solved your own question, please add an answer to describe how :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the wallet couldn't recognize the utxo with `listunspent` because I put the wrong private key into the descriptor. `rawtr(KEY)` takes a *tweaked* private key and I accidentally put the *untweaked* private key into it. After I corrected the wallet was able to recognize and spend the utxo.